# Merge/Zip/Copy two dynamic frame together in Glue

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I am working on a simple ETL process that shall extract certain columns out of am AWS RDS (postgres). The main challenge is, that most of the information is in one "json-column" just as a simple string.

**My Approach so far:**

```py
# Setup Glue and get RDS
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="db", table_name="table")

# Get the fields
sel_df = df.select_fields(["regular", "bigjson"])

# Unpack the json
json_df = sel_df.unbox("bigjson", "json")

# Get the fields we need from the json
json_fields = json_df.select_fields(["A", "B", "C"])

# Want to do something like this
final_df = sel_df.select_fields(["regular"])
final_df = final_df.merge(json_fields, vertical=true) # copies the columns
```

This works so far. Now i want to create a new Dynamic frame using the columns from the DF json_fields and sel_df. This should be possible because non of my transformations so far changed the number of rows.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to copy them together?

Comment: Did you try the mergeDynamicFrame method? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-merge